# litespeed cache works but after some time site gets to redirect into redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, cache, cloudflare

I have a WP one page website on which i enabled light speed cache plugin which improved site performance but on the other side side goes into redirect loop which crashes the site. I was not able to find any reason for this.

for example my domain `https://example.com/` gets into redirect loop and each time it gets in redirect loop it points to `https://example.com/?utm_source=Google%20&utm_medium=Organic&utm_campaign=GMB&utm_id=GMB` i did look into this few days back but was not able to pin point issue.

I have a simple site for which i am using cloudflare CDN and also configure light speed based on tutorials with basic configuration with out image optimization as i upload image only once i optimse them individually

Some tutorials points to Cloudflare, some pointed to lightspeed but it hard for me to trouble shoot this issue and i am not able to figure of reason for redirect.

Redirect stops once i purge all cache from Plugin and then i dont know when it will break again.

i also noticed that this issue is not related to local browser redirect as i tried same on different device and using VPN when redirect loop starts it happens to everone accessing the site

i tried [this blog](https://kinsta.com/blog/err_too_many_redirects/) also to resolve this is issue and some other blogs

anyone pointer are appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of using WordPress for a single page site?   Couldn't you just save the page as static HTML and upload it to a server and get much better performance?   Or do you need dynamic capabilities or ability to edit that page that WordPress provides?

Comment: Page needs frequent updates, so its dynamic in nature which changes on weekly basis such as offers, events etc... contents are not much for multi-page site but requirement is for CMS from client so that they can update. otherwise yes static page will make sense and will improve page performance at-least by 50% or more....